# Auto correct indentation errors in Python

Tags: python, indentation

I am trying fix some indentation errors in a Python script. Is there a way to auto correct the errors online or using other utilities?

I hope this error is very familiar, but wanted to avoid this again. Does any editor help in fixing these issues?

> IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: Pylint should point you at the line numbers.

Comment: Use an IDE supports Python indentation such as LiClips

Answer (score 7):

It's not possible in general because some cases would be ambiguous:

```
something = foo()
if something:
    something.bar()
  print("ok") # Only half indented. Should this be inside or outside of the if statement?
```

It's much better to find an editor with auto-indentation support and make sure you indent properly (even in languages without significant whitespaces, as it makes your code easier to read).

Comment: Hey, thanks very much. is there a tool that you would recommend for auto-indentation, not to fix but to auto-indent when writing a script?

Comment: @user3721640: Take a look at the huge list on https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonEditors . Any decent text editor suitable for programming should be configurable to support Python, to some degree. However, while auto-indenting is easy, auto-dedenting isn't since the editor can't guess what you want your code to do. FWIW, I use often use Kate, the primary KDE editor, but I also use [Geany](http://www.geany.org).

Comment: @user3721640 Spyder works well for dedenting easily enough (shift-tab over a highlighted block or line).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [reindent.py](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Tools/scripts/reindent.py).

For me, it worked on some files, but it didn't work on others.  Give it a try.

Usage:

```
reindent.py <filename>.py
```

Change Python (.py) files to use 4-space indents and no hard tab characters.

Also trim excess spaces and tabs from ends of lines, and remove empty lines
at the end of files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spyder IDE

Source Menu -> Fix Indentation

[image]

Answer (score -2):

This particular error usually occurs when you forget to add an indented block after a statement that needs one (i.e. `if` or `for`). You likely forgot to indent the required block or accidentally hit backspace (or something) such as

```
def sayhello():
print "Hello world!"
```

Sometimes you don't want any code after an if statement or after try/except statements, but python will require at least one line after them, so you can use the [`pass`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#pass) keyword

```
try:
    x= 4/0
except:
    pass

print x
```

Comment: I think OP clearly knows what an IndentationError is. This answer is not really helpful.