# Fixing spacing errors in python code in vscode automatically

Tags: python, intellisense, visual-studio-code

In python code in vscode I am getting the following error

`unindent does not match any outer indentation level (<unknown>, line 33)pylint(syntax-error)`

This error was showing as a red mark at line `return traversal`

I noticed that there is a lack of space in the `is statement` and correcting it fixed the error. Now this is weird it didn't show the error mark at right place.

Also I think there must be some option in `vscode` to automatically fix such errors.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If VSC would fix this automatic it would automatically write my program, indentation determines the logic

Comment: Well intellij does automatically fixes lot of things in Java

Comment: Because you can write all your Java code on 1 line and still have a working program

Comment: The difference is that Java doesn't care about indentation, it is mostly to enable humans to understand easily if indented logically. Python requires indentation to determine logic, for example in an if statement, there are no closing curlies, the statement ends when the indentation does. VSCode cannot automatically indent because as said above, it would be writing your program for you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Auto correct indentation errors in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30215496/auto-correct-indentation-errors-in-python)