# how to auto fix python IndentationError in vscode with black formatter?

Tags: python, vscode-extensions, indentation, formatter

I am using VSCode to write Python code and I noticed that the Black formatter is unable to fix my indentation issues. For instance, consider this code:

```py
def test():
        print(111)
    print(222)
```

It simply doesn't correct the indentation. After examining the output from the Black formatter, I found this:

```py
  File ".vscode\extensions\ms-python.black-formatter-2023.2.0\bundled\tool\lsp_server.py", line 87, in is_python
    ast.parse(code)
  File "AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\ast.py", line 47, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, flags,
  File "<unknown>", line 3
    print(222)
             ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

It seems that Black only formats Python files when the `lsp_server` checks them and returns `is_python` as true. However, I need Black to format my code and fix the indentation, so it can be properly complied as python file. Is this a paradox?

I know that I can manually change the indentation to resolve the issue, but what I really want is an automatic fix with the formatter. I would appreciate any assistance or suggestions.

Hope to know how to auto fix python indentation error.

Comment: Black does not change what your code does, only what it looks like. If your code produces an error before formatting, it is going to produce the same error after formatting. If black did anything else, that would be terrible.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Black's documentation](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#why-does-black-not-detect-syntax-errors-in-my-code)

> Black is an autoformatter, not a Python linter or interpreter. Detecting all syntax errors is not a goal.

you cannot automatically get `IndentationError`s fixed, because it is a `SyntaxError`:

```py
In [1]: issubclass(IndentationError, SyntaxError)
Out[1]: True
```

Black can help get a consistent indentation, but not to solve an `IndentationError`.

Automatically fixing `IndentationError`s are very challenging, because how should a program decide which indentation level is the right one? But [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30215496/auto-correct-indentation-errors-in-python) are some directions you can go if you're willing to do so.

Comment: Thank you, I think I get the point. However, I still find it quite surprising that we can't resolve this issue. Hopefully, we can make improvements in the future.

Comment: You need a lot of semantic knowledge to decide if an indentation should move more to the left or better to the right. Simply take a `print` statement which is in the middle of a for-loop indentation level and the indentation level which started the loop. How should a program decide if it should be moved to the left or to the right? You can only decide if you look at the content of the print statement. Worst, even this would not help much. So SyntaxErrors can also be seen as implementation errors. Automatically fixing this is hard. Can maybe be solved in future with AI. But not ambiguous errors

Comment: Yes, I agree with you that ambiguous errors should be fixed by the coder. However, I just realized from my experience that indentation errors often occur when I copy code from one place to another. So, I think if there were a way to avoid that, my problems would actually be solved.

Comment: I would say that this is potentially an issue with the IDE. I suggest opening a bug for a specific unwanted behavior you encounter by copy/paste code snippets. Nevertheless, after code is written by hand or copied, it doesn't matter, black cannot fix this automatically as already explained. Consider to upvote/accept this answer if you think your question is well answered.